# Azure AD + Graph API: How to reconsent after new permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an application registration in Azure AD which has some Graph API delegated permissions set for it.

The application is simply a page in SharePoint that is making the Graph calls, authenticating with the ADAL.js library.

I now want to make an additional Graph call on the page to a new Graph API endpoint so I need to assign the application an additional permission. I set this permission in Azure AD and save. However, the user accessing the SharePoint page is never asked to reconsent to the new permissions, therefore the new Graph call fails with a 401 Unauthorised message.

I have tried this with a number of different endpoints and permissions, and I am sure I am setting the correct permissions in the application.

**How can I have the consent dialog appear for users automatically when the application permissions change?**

Admin consent is not an option.

Comment: Are you using Azure AD v1 or v2?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure - how can I check? I'm using the new Azure interface, if that's what you're asking...

Comment: I have just discovered something interesting: the app appears at aad.portal.azure.com but not at apps.dev.microsoft.com. I'm not sure what the difference is, but this may answer your question.

Comment: In this case you're using Azure AD v1. Let me propose a solution in a bit.

Answer (score 6):

I remember having a discussion about this with a member of Azure AD team some time back and this is what he had suggested at that time (though I never tried it so it may not work).

Essentially what he suggested is that when you get `Unauthorized (401)` error, you redirect the user to Azure AD login again i.e. follow OAuth authorization flow again but include `prompt=consent` in the sign in URI. This will present the user a consent page with latest permissions. Once the user consents to the latest permission, you can redirect the user back to your application. You may find this link helpful for understanding different values for `propmpt` parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code.

Again, I have not tried this personally so it may not work. If it doesn't, please let me know and I will remove my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: This approach should work - let us know.  If you are using the v2 endpoint for auth, this process becomes slightly easier because it supports "incremental consent".  You'd still need to handle the `Unauthorized (401)`, but you'd simply make a request to the authorize endpoint requesting the additional scope(s) that you need - that would automatically re-prompt the end-user for re-consent.